# I Broke Solitude in Skyrim and Need Help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been playing Skyrim PC recently, and was working through the Civil War questline with the Stormcloaks. I had a bounty of 1,059 gold when I completed the Fort Greenwall quest. I returned to Galmar Stone-Fist and started the Battle for Solitude quest.

On my way to Solitude, I was stopped by a guard and paid off my bounty, resulting in it loading with me outside Castle Dour. Due to that, the quest progressed to where I needed to kill General Tulius inside.

A while later, when attempting to return to Solitude, it didn't show up on my map, so I walked and when I attempted to enter the city, it spawned Ulfric and several Stormcloaks. Ulfric gave a battle speech to pep the troops on to attack the city.

I assumed that I would just have to go through the quest again, and went up to the city, but when I attempted to open the door, I received this message onscreen: "You must help the soldiers defend the city before you can enter."

I waited to see if I could bypass this. I researched online to see if I could complete the quest using commands, but that also came up bust.

I save over my previous save games to conserve space, and so I can't go back to a previous save to retry this. Please help me figure out how to fix this, or uncover my autosaves to go back and redo this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a stormcloak you can use the set-stage console command.
Press the ` button left of the 1 on your keyboard and then type:

> SetStage CWSiegeObj 1

OR

> SetStage CWSiegeObj 1000

To restart the quest to a previous point so you can do it again.
Or if you want to skip the quest entirely:

> SetStage CWSiegeObj 9000

**INPORTANT!** always save before using a console command, seeing it might make things worse if done wrong.

Comment: I am with the Stormcloaks. Using those commands, it says that the quest has been started/completed, but the door is still locked with the message.

Comment: @NiarAlyks personally I'm afraid you are stuck then. Think the only thing you can do is learn o keep at least 5 or so saves. Especially concerning main quests

Comment: SetStage to an earlier stage is *rarely* safe or effective because Bethesda designed the stages to go forwards, not backwards, for most quests in Skyrim. In a case like this, it may be best to use SetStage to skip whatever remains of the quest (use SQS CWSiegeObj1 to see the stages and whether they are complete), and then leave the area and wait for it to respawn naturally (usually 10 or 30 in-game days without the player being near it).